# Attract tourists from "around the world" or "[all] around the world"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

**Attract tourists from around the world** and **attract tourists from *all* around the world**.

Are they both correct? If they are, is the former used more commonly?

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Both are gramatically correct, and there's no important difference between the two. "All" is very slightly intensifying of the phrase _around the world._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I noticed that you delete the "thank you", I read your post about this matter and thought it is only for replying "thank you". I really think I should express my thankfulness to people and that is not chatty. People take their time to help others, why can't they receive some appreciation?

Comment: We know you're grateful, and you are very welcome! If you read the thread on the subject, so you may understand the reasons for removing them. Everyone appreciates gratitude, but to subsequent readers (and to some current ones) gratitude doesn't add any information; to some readers, it is even distracting. We encourage thank-yous in comments. I like thank-you's myself! But in a question or answer, they can detract a little from the value. If it is very important to you that your "thank you" is preserved, it is easily restored, but I hope you'll think about why it was removed.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think oppositely. If I thank people by adding a comment to their reply, I think they will receive a notification and they have to click on it to read it, which it's time-consuming (especially for people who answer lots of questions). I think it is much easier to thank people in advance. Also, I don't think having 'thank you' at the end of the question is a much of distraction to future readers, I think thank people is a good habit. Anyway, I consider this place is more than a reference, it's also a community. Just like to let to hear the opposite voice so I typed this :)

Comment: No one ever thinks a questioner is rude or ungrateful because they _don't_ include "Thank you!" (And most questioners don't.) ELL is a reference in the Q&A. In the comments, it has some features of a community, but that's not what it's meant to be. There's a good thread on the subject [**here.**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1367/37009) I hope you'll take a few minutes to read it. We're here to help, and we love doing it! But we want the questions and answers to be as informative as possible. The personalities of questioner and answerer aren't part of the information.